# Gmail Markup - Invoice

Tags: google-schemas

a while ago my email "info@x.com" was approved for gmail markup  . In our company we send invoice to pay our clients and these invoices have an expiration date. What I was looking for is that the day the invoice expires, our clients receive a notification that their invoice is due today, as in the following image:

[google assistant notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nndlM.png)

It turns out that this notification is not reaching my clients, and I checked the markup and it is correct, I comply with all the requirements that they asked me, but I cannot get that notification. If you could please help me and tell me if this service depends on gmail markup, I would appreciate it very much, thank you very much,